# Why successfully finished tasks on lost executor are resubmitted?

Tags: apache-spark

We have an OutOfMemoryError in a task causing the executor to be killed.
The successfully finished tasks already processed by this executor are resubmitted.

As shuffle files created by the successfully finished tasks should be written on local filesystem. Why are these tasks resubmitted ?

Edit :
We use Ambari as cluster manager, YARN as resource manager. 
The external shuffle service is disabled in Spark.
[image]

Comment: What cluster manager? Do you use external shuffle service? How the DAG / execution plan looks like? How do you determine that the tasks are resubmitted?

Comment: I edited my question, it seems to be caused by the disabled external shuffle service in Spark. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reuse shuffle files, after executor has been decommissioned, you have to at least enable external shuffle service. Otherwise there is no process that can actually serve the files to the newly spawned executor.

Steps you have to follow to enable it differ from manager to manager and are described in the official guides for the respective manager ([Standalone](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup), [Mesos](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#dynamic-resource-allocation-with-mesos), [YARN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuring-the-external-shuffle-service)).

However external shuffle service depends on access to share file storage, so might not work well in containerized environments and such. You can read more about this problem in [SPARK-25299](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25299) and [the accompanying design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uCkzGGVG17oGC6BJ75TpzLAZNorvrAU3FRd2X-rVHSM/edit#heading=h.btqugnmt2h40).